# TSQL merge: target table where on "ON" condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

I want to use `merge`, and am intimidated by this warning from the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) concerning the `ON` join condition:

> It is important to specify only the columns from the target table that
>   are used for matching purposes. That is, specify columns from the
>   target table that are compared to the corresponding column of the
>   source table. Do not attempt to improve query performance by filtering
>   out rows in the target table in the ON clause, such as by specifying
>   AND NOT target_table.column_x = value. Doing so may return unexpected
>   and incorrect results.

Here's an example:

```
-- drop table trg
create table trg(department int not null,student int not null,name nvarchar(20))
alter table trg add constraint PK_trg primary key clustered (department,student)
insert trg values (12,0,'Tony'),(12,1,'Helen'),(55,0,'Tony'),(55,1,'Helen')

-- drop table src 
go
create table src(student int not null,name nvarchar(20)) 
go
alter table src add constraint PK_src primary key clustered (student) 
go
insert src values (0,'Antony'),(1,'Helen'),(2,'Mike')

select * from trg
select * from src
```

The trg table

```
+------------+---------+-------+
| department | student | name  |
+------------+---------+-------+
|         12 |       0 | Tony  |
|         12 |       1 | Helen |
|         55 |       0 | Tony  |
|         55 |       1 | Helen |
+------------+---------+-------+
```

Has 2 students in two departments (please ignore the 2nf violation, the third col should be dependent on department too, but I can't think of an example now).

Now, we are given a `src` table who has info *only* concerning department 12:

```
+---------+--------+
| student |  name  |
+---------+--------+
|       0 | Antony |
|       1 | Helen  |
|       2 | Mike   |
+---------+--------+
```

...and we want to upsert this info in `src` with `merge`.

Using this:

```
merge trg using src on trg.student=src.student and trg.department=12
    when matched then update set name=src.name
    when not matched by target then insert values (12,src.student,src.name)
;
```

Does what we intended. trg table now has the desired output:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
| department | student |  name  |
+------------+---------+--------+
|         12 |       0 | Antony |
|         12 |       1 | Helen  |
|         12 |       2 | Mike   |
|         55 |       0 | Tony   |
|         55 |       1 | Helen  |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

We can see that department 12 Tony had name changed to Antony, Mike was inserted with department 12, and nothing else happened. This was made by *violating* the reference warning. Is that OK?

I suppose it could be re-written as:

```
merge trg using src on trg.student=src.student
    when matched and trg.department=12 then update set name=src.name
    when not matched by target then insert values (12,src.student,src.name);
```

Which indeed also works correctly.

**Is the first way that contradicts the warning wrong, or bad practice? Why?**

Comment: Hello, ask ... Antony, Helen and Mike are new students in department 12? If so, the problem is not the reference since your relationship is by the column "student", that is ... Student 0 = Tony -> Mike, Student 1 = Helen -> Helen, 2 = NULL -> Mike ( new row), therefore, in the combine condition would also include the name ... greetings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the warning is that if your source table contains something like `55,0,Tony` then this will be treated as unmatched and go to the `INSERT` branch which may be unexpected.

However if your source table is guaranteed to only contain items with department 12 then this will work as you want.

You might also use a table expression such as a CTE in this case

```
WITH trg12
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   trg
         WHERE  department = 12)
MERGE trg12 trg
using src
ON trg.student = src.student
WHEN matched THEN
  UPDATE SET name = src.name
WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN
  INSERT
  VALUES (12,
          src.student,
          src.name);
;
```

Comment: Thanks. This will be a useful reference.